# Convert blank to NULL for a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my table I have few columns which are having blank values. Can anyone suggest me a query by which I can replace all blanks to NULL for a given table?

**EDIT**

I am sorry if I couldn't specify my question correctly, I don't want to give the column name in my query. All I have is the table name. So, for a given table I want to check all columns and convert their blank values to NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an approach next stored procedure could be help:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE up_replaceBlanksByNulls
    @schemaName nvarchar(50),
    @tableName nvarchar(100)
AS
declare @query1 nvarchar(max) = ''

 select @query1 = @query1 + 'UPDATE ' + @schemaName + '.' + @tableName + ' SET ' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ' = NULL WHERE ' +
  c.COLUMN_NAME + ' = '''';' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
  WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = @tableName  
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @query1
GO
```

Usage:

```
up_replaceBlanksByNulls 'dbo', 'myTable'
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Query is executed successfully. I have replaced *myTableName* with my SQL Table. Do I have to change any other thing here ?

Comment: I am not getting any error, it is executing successfully but the table columns are not updating with NULL. When I am running the second query it is always returing this statement *((1 row(s) affected)**. Still none of the rows modified. I have so many blanks in the table :-(

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite, few questions: what schema your table belongs to? Is `implicit transactions` turned off or on?

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite, and one more question: does `blank` value mean completely empty string - '', or it could contains whitespaces or tabs, or smth like that?

Comment: This is the script of my schema **CREATE SCHEMA [WorkTables] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]**

Comment: How to find that it has white spaces or blank?

Comment: When I used below query I got tons of blank: **SELECT myColumn FROM [Databasename].[WorkTables].[tbl_Customer] WHERE DATALENGTH(myColumn) = 0**

Comment: Same rowcount with this query **SELECT myColumn FROM [Databasename].[WorkTables].[tbl_Customer] WHERE myColumn = ''**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16288/discussion-between-aleksey-berezan-and-zerotoinfinite)

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of all blank values in a table :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getRidOfBlanks 
    @tableName nvarchar(50)
    AS
    DECLARE @colName varchar(50)
    DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    select COLUMN_NAME
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where TABLE_NAME='@tableName'
    OPEN Table_Cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @colName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN
          UPDATE @tableName SET @colName = NULL WHERE @colName = '';
          FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @colName
       END;
    CLOSE Table_Cursor;
    DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor;
    GO
```

To use this, you create your procedure with my code, then you execute it with your tableName.

Comment: @lagrandmere Sorry about my unclear question, please check the edit part. I have only table name with me

Comment: @TimSchmelter edited my answer to get rid of all blank values in a table.

Comment: Strange but I am getting this error when I am creating this SP **Must declare the table variable "@tableName".**

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite You need to add your table name instead of `@tableName`.

Comment: @hims056 I believe then I need to hardcode the table name. Quite good for my purpose but can't be used for stored procedure. +1

Answer (score 1):

Simply using `UPDATE` like this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = NULL WHERE myColumn = '';
```

Comment: and with multiple columns as OP wants(_"few columns "_)?

Comment: @hims056 Sorry about my unclear question, please check the edit part. I have only table name with me

Answer (score 1):

If your column names have spaces in them, here is an alteration of @alex.b procedure.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE up_replaceBlanksByNulls
    @schemaName nvarchar(50),
    @tableName nvarchar(100)
AS
declare @query1 nvarchar(max) = ''

 select @query1 = @query1 + 'UPDATE ' + @schemaName + '.' + @tableName + ' SET ' + case when c.COLUMN_NAME like '% %' then '[' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ']' Else c.COLUMN_NAME end + ' = NULL WHERE ' +
  case when c.COLUMN_NAME like '% %'  then '[' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ']' Else c.COLUMN_NAME end + ' = '''';' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
  WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = @tableName  
  print @query1
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @query1
GO
```