# Update column with default values from temporary table

Tags: sql-server-2008, temp-tables

I have stored a result set on a temporary table which has

```
Column_Name, Data_Type, Default_Value
Col1         varchar      abc
Col2         varchar      abc
Col3         int          999
Col4         decimal      0.0
Col5         datetime     20120101
```

Now I have to build a statement which will Compare the column name with the column name of the table and based on the datatype of the temporary table it will assign the default value to it whenever column value is NULL.

I have no clue how to do that

This is what I have done till now

```
  CREATE TABLE #ColumnData (Column_Name varchar(500), Data_Type varchar(20),
```

Default_Value varchar(50))

```
 DECLARE @query1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = '' 
  DECLARE @SchemaName VARCHAR(20)
  DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(50)

SET @SchemaName = 'dbo'
SET @TableName = 'tblCustomer'





     select @query1 = @query1 + 'UPDATE ' + @schemaName + '.' + @tableName + ' SET ' + 
     c.COLUMN_NAME + ' = ' + c.Default_Value+ ' WHERE ' +   c.COLUMN_NAME 
     + ' = ''NULL'';' FROM #ColumnData c  
     WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = @tableName     

      EXECUTE sp_executesql @query1
```

Comment: I have tried to join my temprory table with InformationSchema.Columns based on the column name and tried to update the column but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.  Tested it out in SQL 2008.

```
update t
set t.col1 = isnull(t.col1, tr.col1) 
    t.col2 = isnull(t.col1, tr.col2)
    etc.
from my_table t
cross join temp_table tr
```

***Update:***

-- create your temp table like this, then set all the default values in a single row (note the `_temp` on the end of the temp table name).

```
select * into #MyTable_temp from dbo.MyTable where 1=1
```

---

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'update t set ' 
DECLARE @SchemaName VARCHAR(20) 
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(50) 

SET @SchemaName = 'dbo' 
SET @TableName = 'MyTable' 

set @query = @query + ( 
        select stuff((
            select ', ' + c.column_name + ' = isnull(t.' + c.column_name + ', tt.' + c.column_name + ')'
            from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
            where c.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
            for xml path('')), 1, 2, ''))

set @query = @query + ' from ' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + ' t cross join #' + @TableName + '_temp tt'

select @query
```

Your query should look like this:

```
update t 
    set Col1 = isnull(t.Col1, tt.Col1), 
        Col2 = isnull(t.Col2, tt.Col2), 
        Col3 = isnull(t.Col3, tt.Col3), 
        Col4 = isnull(t.Col4, tt.Col4), 
        etc... 
from dbo.MyTable t 
cross join #MyTable_temp tt
```

Comment: I have 278 columns in a table I can not write this for each column :-(

Comment: Thanks :-) Just to update you I have asked a question few days back to change column value to NULL if it is blank. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278278/convert-blank-to-null-for-a-table Hope this will help...

Actually I am trying to use the same method to replace null with default value

Comment: 'select @ query1 = @ query1 + 'UPDATE ' + @ schemaName + '.' + @ tableName + ' SET ' + 
         c.COLUMN_NAME + ' =' + c.Default_Value+ 'WHERE ' +   c.COLUMN_NAME 
         + ' = ''NULL'';' FROM #ColumnData c  
         WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = @ tableName     
          
          EXECUTE sp_executesql @query1'

Comment: I have modified the query now there is no syntax issue, but still it is not updating the table. :-(

Comment: The only issue I am facing now is that SQL is saying invalid column name for all tt.Columns